# Cordova - cordova platform add android access denied

Tags: android, cordova

I recently have setup my dev environment to work with Phonegap/Cordova and I am getting a weird success when I add the android platform

I run the command cordova platform add android, it goes through doing its thing and right before it tells me Project successfully created it has Access is denied.

Any ideas? is this an issue?

full cli log including commands:
http://pastebin.com/RBcSgyAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks quite similar to the issue stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/6AoOIBXsiy8). Most likely an Antivirus problem, try to disable it temporarily and execute the `cordova platform add android` command again.

Also, I noticed that your drive volume is `J:`, is this a network drive? That could also lead to problems.